# Какой командой убрать предупреждения python / jupyter_notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

В jupiter notebook при выполнении часто сталкиваюсь с:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZQOU.png

```
[![D:\Anaconda_3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:528: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for example using ravel().
  estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
```

Как убрать/отключить ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```